# How to make Jenkins job success on specific error exit code other than 0?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I was trying to install a plugin through jenkins job. When it goes for restart , the exit code is 1641. But the installation is successful. So I want to make the build successful. 
I am using "setup.exe /qb /log C:\installer.log /r:f" this command for silent install and force restart.

How can I mark the build successful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jenkins will exit with the result of the last command. You just need to catch it and tell Jenkins how to exit.

Linux - `RESULT=$?`
Windows - `set RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%`

After catching the command's result, you can put an `if` on it to decide how to exit.

Linux - `if [ $RESULT -eq 1641 ]; then exit 0; fi`
Windows - `if %RESULT% EQ 1641 exit 0`

I hope this helps.